# Initializing struct within a function then storing its address

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hi I have a struct like this

```
struct small_struct {
  int a;
  int b;
}

struct big_struct {
  struct *small_struct child;
}
```

I want to pass the pointer of `big_struct` as a parameter into a function in which `child` is initialized.

```
static int my_function(struct big_struct* s) {
  if (certain_condition)
    s->child = &(struct small_struct) {
      .a = 1;
      .b = 2;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this and `my_function` is finished, the fields in `s->child` are often changed outside of the `my_function`. Would there be a way to keep `a` and `b` values as it was initialized inside `my_function`?

Thank you!

Comment: When you use a compound literal inside a function, the lifetime of the data ends when the function returns. You need to use `malloc()` to allocate the memory dynamically.

Comment: It looks like you're dynamically allocating a new instance of "struct small_struct" on the stack inside of my_function().  That instance is *no longer valid* once my_function() exits.  Two workarounds are 1) malloc() small_struct, or 2) declare small_struct inside of big_struct (instead of defining child as "struct small_struct *", declare child as ""struct small_struct".

Comment: Is there a reason that `child` has to be a pointer, instead of an instance of `small_struct`?

Comment: The best solution is indeed to include the small struct as a member variable of the big struct, rather than as a pointer.

Comment: @Barmar, nitpicking, the lifetime of a compound literal ends when the *block* containing it ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
s->child = &(struct small_struct) {
  .a = 1;
  .b = 2;
}
```

This creates the struct in the **stack** memory of the function, then assigns the  `s->child` pointer to that memory. As soon as the function returns, that memory is no longer allocated to your struct. What you need to do is allocate **heap** memory for the structure, using `malloc`, which will stay allocated until it is free'd with a call to `free`:

```
static int my_function(struct big_struct* s) {
if (certain_condition)
{
    //Allocate *heap* memory for the pointer
    //This must be freed later!
    //e.g free(s.child);
    s->child = malloc(sizeof(struct small_struct));
    s->child->a = 1;
    s->child->b = 2;
}
```

Alternatively, depending on what you are trying to do, don't make `child` a pointer, that way the memory is already allocated in the instance of `big_struct` e.g.:

```
struct big_struct 
{
  struct small_struct child; //Note: not a pointer
};

static int my_function(struct big_struct* s) {
  if (certain_condition)
  {
    //Memory for child member is already allocated
    s->child.a = 1;
    s->child.b = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what  user3386109 and I were trying to tell the OP.  With an excellent example/explanation.